# RESTEasy JAX-RS application not calling @PreDestroy

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jax-rs, resteasy, shutdown

I'm using RESTEasy 3.1.0.CR3 with its servlet initializer in Tomcat 8.5, via annotations (no `web.xml`):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.CR3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have a JAX-RS application that I need to know before it is destroyed/uninstalled from the container, so that I can release some resources (stop a thread):

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyRESTApplication extends Application {

  …

  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    …
  }

  @Override
  public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
    …
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void end() {
    //TODO release resources
  }
```

But my `end()` method doesn't seem to be called. Am I doing this wrong? Is there a better way to detect when a JAX-RS application is taken down?

Comment: [I think this is a bug related](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1982) And sorry I'm getting confused with an entitie bean. I don't know if JAX-RS have the method PostDestroy

Comment: What does a Jersey bug have to do with RESTEasy?

Comment: Can you create a repository with a complete example? I can't see anything thats wrong with the code you have given so far.

Comment: Adam, have you ever used RESTEasy with a web application without a `web.xml` file and using the servlet initializer dependency on a non-JAX-RS aware container such as Tomcat?

Comment: How are checking the same that it is being called or not .

I did redeploy of application and it was called sysout in it was printed. Hope you are not stopping the server you will never know then

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be quite a big oversight in the JAX-RS specification. See the following discussion:

[[jax-rs-spec users] Fwd: Lifecycle management in Application subclasses](https://java.net/projects/jax-rs-spec/lists/users/archive/2012-12/message/11)

Some reasonable workaround would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is supported. For `@PreDestory` the same rule applies like for `@PostConstruct`:

> This annotation MUST be supported on all classes that support dependency injection.

Is dependency injection in an `Application` class supported? A JAX-RS implementation may integrate Managed Beans, EJBs or CDI but this is optional. JAX-RS itself provides dependency injection via `@Context` but explicitly *not* in an `Application` class (ch. 9.2.1 of the specification).

So `@PreDestory` may work in some environments but there's no guarantee.

In your environment I would implement a custom `ServletContextListener` and release resources in `#contextDestroyed`. Your `Application` class should be accessible [via the ServletContext](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/blob/3.1.0.CR3/resteasy-jaxrs/src/main/java/org/jboss/resteasy/plugins/server/servlet/ListenerBootstrap.java#L49):

```java
Map<String, ResteasyDeployment> deployments = (Map<String, ResteasyDeployment>)
    request.getServletContext().getAttribute("resteasy.deployments");
ResteasyDeployment deployment = deployments.get("/application/path");
Application application = deployment.getApplication();
```

You could also handle everything in a custom `ServletContextListener` without the Application class and store references as ServletContext Attributes.

Comment: And how would my `ServletContextListener` get a reference to my JAX-RS application? (There are multiple instances of this application running on the same server, and each has resources it needs to free when shutting down.)

Comment: Sorry, did you answer my question "And how would my ServletContextListener get a reference to my JAX-RS application?"

Comment: Of course there is an instance of the application. Otherwise how could the instance methods be called? This is Java 101; it sort of lowers my confidence in your answer.

Comment: Nothing in `ResteasyServletInitializer` can change the fact that 1) my REST application constructor is being called, and 2) if I make my REST application implement `ServletContextListener`, then my application is instantiated _twice_ (which I definitely do _not_ want), once because it is a REST application, and again because it has a `@WebListener` annotation (which is what I need to make the `ServletContextListener` work in the absence of a `web.xml` file). I think I'll suspend further comments to this answer unless I see something more substantial. But thanks for thinking about this.