# @PreDestroy not invoked in JAX-RS resource, how do I close/release resources?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jetty, predestroy

I have a java class annotated with the `jakarta.ws.rs-api` annotations, which is a rest resource class. I have created an executor service as part of the resource class (which contains methods with annotations like @GET, @PUT, etc.), and am looking for a way to close this executor service upon the shutdown of the servlet container (jetty using jersey).
I came across @PreDestroy annotation, used it in the resource class, but it isn't getting invoked upon graceful shutdown of the container.

Is there a way where the resources like executor-service in a resource class can be closed with a predefined hook or annotation? Thanks!

Comment: I remember having to do cleanup like this using a `contextDestroyed` method on a `Servlet`. Although I don't remember if it was because of Jersey not properly calling those `@PreDestroy` methods, or something to do with Tomcat, or with Guice. But at least this may give you another option to look at.

Comment: It's indeed overlooked in JAX-RS: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41187018. Theoretically, if CDI is available, you could use an Extension to patch this.

Answer (score 0):

One way of listening to the container's "shutdown" could be using an implementation of ServletContextListener interface, and writing the logic for closing your executor service under the contextDestroyed(ServletContext) method.